# Missing Instance Data for this DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, jquery, html-helper, datetimepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

I am having these two textboxes for start date and end date. On These two textboxes I use datepicker. Also I am having an uplodify on this page. When I fill the date on these textboxes and click on upload button to upload picture. I got the following error as `"Missing Instance Data for this DateTimePicker"`

Code for HTml:

```
   <div class="clearfix mrb10">
                        <div class="vp-dt-left">@Resources.Languages.Start<span class="orange">*</span>:</div>
                        <div class="vp-dt-right">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "vp-box-input-125 SelectDate requiredField", @readonly = "readonly", @Style = "width:72px!important;" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="vp-dt-left">@Resources.Languages.End<span class="orange">*</span>:</div>
                        <div class="vp-dt-right">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "vp-box-input-125 SelectDate requiredField", @readonly = "readonly", @Style = "width:72px!important;" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$('.SelectDate').datepicker({
            });
```

Script File:

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Which datepicker are you using? show us the all the js files which you have included.

Comment: The following is the Script file which I had used: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same in my code using jquery datepicker. Hope it will help you :-

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, new { style = "width: 200px;" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToDate, new { style = "width: 200px;" })


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ToDate").datepicker(
     {
         beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
             inst.dpDiv.css({ marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px' });
         },
         changeYear: true,
         yearRange: '-2:' + new Date().getFullYear(),
         onClose: function (selectedDate) {
             $("#FromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
         },
     });
    $("#FromDate").datepicker(
    {
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            inst.dpDiv.css({ marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px' });
        },
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '-2:' + new Date().getFullYear(),
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#ToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```